# Two Model Popup's in a Same Page

Tags: c#, ajax

I am working in C#.Net and Ajax Concepts. I am having 2 ModelPopup Extender in a page. I am also having 2 Buttons in that page. When i click the 1st Button 1 MP should be displayed and when i click the 2nd Button, 2nd MP should get displayed. This works fine for me for the first time. [i.e] When i click the 1st Button, 1st MP is displayed and When i click the 2nd Button, 2nd MP is displayed and once again if i click the 1st Button nothing happens.

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="Button2">
                        </ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" ToolTip="Location" runat="server" Text="Location(+)"
                            OnClientClick="LocClick();" />
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Style="display: block; width: 600px; overflow: scroll;
                            height: 440px;" BackColor="White">
                            <table>
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td width="650">
                                        <ct:ASTreeView ID="astvMyTree" runat="server" BasePath="~/Scripts/astreeview/" DataTableRootNodeValue="0"
                                            BackColor="White" EnableRoot="false" EnableNodeSelection="true" EnableCheckbox="false"
                                            EnableDragDrop="false" EnableTreeLines="true" EnableNodeIcon="false" EnableCustomizedNodeIcon="false"
                                            EnableDebugMode="false" EnableContextMenuAdd="false" EnableParentNodeExpand="false"
                                            EnableAjaxOnEditDelete="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnOnSelectedNodeChanged="astvMyTree_OnSelectedNodeChanged" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div id="divConsole" runat="server">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel2"
                            TargetControlID="Button1">
                        </ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" ToolTip="Product" runat="server" Text="Product(+)"
                            OnClientClick="ProdClick();" />
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Style="display: block; width: 600px; overflow: scroll;
                            height: 440px;" BackColor="White">
                            <table>
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <td width="650">
                                        <ct:ASTreeView ID="ASTreeView1" runat="server" BasePath="~/Scripts/astreeview/" DataTableRootNodeValue="0"
                                            BackColor="White" EnableRoot="false" EnableNodeSelection="true" EnableCheckbox="false"
                                            EnableDragDrop="false" EnableTreeLines="true" EnableNodeIcon="false" EnableCustomizedNodeIcon="false"
                                            EnableDebugMode="false" EnableContextMenuAdd="false" EnableParentNodeExpand="false"
                                            EnableAjaxOnEditDelete="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnOnSelectedNodeChanged="astvMyTree_OnSelectedNodeChanged" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div id="div4" runat="server">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am just changing the back color of buttons in LocClick as well as ProdClick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function LocClick() {
    var location = document.getElementById("<%= Button2.ClientID %>");
    location.style.background = '#72BD66';
    var product = document.getElementById("<%= Button1.ClientID %>");
    product.style.background = '#065581';
    var lastYear = document.getElementById('<%=chkLastYear.ClientID%>');
    lastYear.checked = false;
 }
```

How to fix this...

Comment: What are you doing in the functions LocClick() and ProdClick()?

Comment: i am jus changing the back color of button in both the methods (LocClick and ProdClick). I had updated my above code..

Comment: Can you try taking out the OnClientClick completely and see if that makies any difference?

Comment: i had removed both onclientclick. no difference..same issue is coming...

Comment: That is most odd then.  I think the next step would be to start breakpointing in the Page_Load and examining what is being posted back in the request when it is working vs when it is not.